# Unable to set specific resolution for 2K display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, hdmi, display-resolution

I have a new 2K (QHD) display that I am trying to use with a Ubuntu 19.04 laptop.

`lspci | grep VGA` produces

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)`.

Regarding the question whether I'm using `x11` or `wayland`,

`loginctl show-session $(awk '/tty/ {print $1}' <(loginctl)) -p Type | awk -F= '{print $2}'` produces `x11` (cf. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325972/322894)).

I've been at it for hours and found that the canonical way to do this is by doing
`cvt 2560 1440 60`, which produces

`Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync`

and then

`xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync`,

followed by

`xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "2560x1440_60.00"`.

At this point, I am able to select the new setting in the settings app for the desired screen. However, I prefer activiating it via `xrandr --output`, since that produces error messages. Now when I do

`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "2560x1440_60.00"`,

all three screens (the laptop screen, the 2K screen and another screen that is connected to the laptop, too) go black for 5 seconds and then everything goes back to normal and the terminal shows

`xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed`.

Is there anything more I can do to make this work?

**Details:**

- The 2K screen is connected to the laptop via a DisplayPort to HDMI cable (DP on the laptop, HDMI on the screen)
- The other display is connected via VGA
- I've tried using this screen on the same computer on Win10 (dual boot), which works flawlessly in 2K
- `xrandr --verbose` produces in the `HDMI-1` section (apart from the list of available resolutions which is omitted for brevity but does contain my newly added resolution)

```
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (0xa6) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  3338504
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:     DP-1
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      1 0 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0030aecf6501010101
        251c0103a0351e782a0e35a4544d9d26
        0f5054bfcf00d1c0d100b300a9c09500
        818081c0714f565e00a0a0a029503020
        35000f282100001a000000ff00553556
        30563642310a20202020000000fd0017
        4c0f5a19000a202020202020000000fc
        004c3234712d31300a202020202001d5
        02031ef04b10050403021f1413121101
        230907078301000065030c001000023a
        801871382d40582c45000f282100001f
        011d8018711c1620582c25000f282100
        009f011d007251d01e206e2855000f28
        2100001e8c0ad08a20e02d10103e9600
        0f2821000018023a80d072382d40102c
        45800f282100001e00000000000000aa
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 84 
        supported: 84
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
```